# sudo stdout: unicorn_appname_production: unrecognized service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano3

I have a ubuntu server with nginx, rails, ruby, unicorn and capistrano, I have got it all setup, and there is no problems when I run

> cap production deploy:check

but when I run

> cap production deploy

I get this error:

> sudo stdout: unicorn_frank_production: unrecognized service

It fails running

> /usr/bin/env sudo service unicorn_appname_production restart

And I think the problem is the last "_production", because when I just run the command

> /usr/bin/env sudo service unicorn_appname restart

It works great, but I don't know how to change capistranos command, so any help on this matter would be very appreciated!

[deploy.rb](http://pastie.org/10547632)

[Capfile](http://pastie.org/10547634)

Comment: Could you post the output of running the Capistrano deployment? Thanks!

Comment: And your Capfile and deploy.rb

Comment: Capistrano output error: 
http://pastie.org/10547635

Comment: Is it your `symlinks` section definition that is not as expected? `"/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}"` may need to `_#{fetch(:stage)}` (I don't remember the keyword, though).

Comment: I didn't change anything, still the same error. Is the not a way where I can change the capistrano's task, so that it calls 
`unicorn_frank`, instead of `unicorn_frank_production` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `capistrano/unicorn_nginx` defaults its `unicorn_service` variable to the form `"unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}"` as seen in https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-unicorn-nginx/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/unicorn.rake#L9

If in your `deploy.rb`, you added:

```
set :unicorn_service, -> { "unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}" }
```

That should make it do what you expect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the job!!